# Execute commands on EC2 using subprocess and aws ssm

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, subprocess, stdin, aws-ssm

I am working with group of EC2 instances that are deployed in a subnet.

I usually use the aws ssm command

```
aws ssm start-session --region us-east-2 --target i-01234567abcdef --profile profile-one
```

to connect to that ec2 instance and run commands such as

```
ssh mirrora
```

to go into a different ec2 instance in the subnet from the one I am connected to

Then I can run ls on mirrora to look at the files and such.

Now I am trying to automate the same using python

I am new to python (and first time working with subprocess). I have researched a bit and learned that I can use Popen to open a subprocess and I set the stdin and stdout arguments to subprocess.PIPE

Here's a sample of the code I am trying to execute

```
command = "aws ssm start-session --region us-east-2 --target i-0123456abcdef --profile profile-one"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, shell= True, universal_newlines=True)

ssh.stdin.write("ssh mirrora")
ssh.stdin.write("ls")
# output = ssh.stdout.read()
# output , err = ssh.communicate()
# print("output:" + output)
# print("err:" + err)
# output = ssh.stdout.read()
# print("Output of ls is:", output)

print("HERE")
```

If I use either `stdout.read` or `communicate` method, the program seems to get stuck and nothing works. I can't even <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> the terminal.

If I run it without any stdout or communicate, it prints "HERE" in the terminal (almost instantaneously) and nothing actually seems to happen on the server side (as I tried to run the shutdown command to turn off the mirrora, but it is still running after program exits without stdout or communicate).

What am I doing wrong?

Ideally I want to run the commands I want inside the subprocess that aws ssm opens and run certain commands on one of the ec2 instances and get the output for one or more commands using `stdout.read` after certain `stdin.write`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should use `run-command` instead `start-session`.

This is an SSM feature used to execute static commands and scripts, where a session is similar to just an ssh connection.

I think it should work like this:

```
import boto3

script = f"""
ssh mirrora 'ls'
ssh mirrora 'ls; ps -aux'
"""
target = "i-01234567abcdef "

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="profile-one")
ssm_client = session.client("ssm")


response = ssm_client.send_command(
    InstanceIds=[target],
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",  # https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/documents/AWS-RunShellScript/description?region=eu-central-1
    TimeoutSeconds=20,
    Comment="Example of send command",
    Parameters={
        'commands': [
            script,
        ],
        'workingDirectory': "/home/user1",
    },
)
```

Here you can find the documentation for send-command API. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command

If you want to view the logs in the python script then you will need to extend it - probably easiest way is to set an s3 bucket in the `send_command` (it will redirect your `stdout` and `stderr` to provided s3 bucket), download saved in s3 files, and cat/print them.

Comment: Thank you! I have used run command and it did what I want it to do